# PHP class for file stream

Tags: php

i just create reading file feature. In general, what kind PHP class that usually use to manipulate the stream of the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Amazing*, the class used to deal with streams is called [Stream](http://uk.php.net/stream)...